# Compute $e^{tA}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, control-theory

When I do my homework (**stability theory**), I must use the knowledge to the matrix. But I don't remember it :(.

**Here's my problem:**

For the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
 & \text{  } \dot{x}(t)=\dfrac{dx}{dt}= 4x-y\\ 
 & \text{  } \dot{y}(t)=\dfrac{dy}{dt}= 3x+y-z\\ 
 & \text{  } \dot{z}(t)=\dfrac{dz}{dt}= x+z
\end{cases} \tag{I}$$
Compute $e^{tA}$.

==============================================================

**Here's my solution:**

We have (I) iff : $$\dot{v}=Av$$, where $v=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}
 & 4 &-1&0 \\ 
 & 3 &1&-1 \\ 
 & 1 & 0&1
\end{pmatrix}$

- I compute the eigenvalues ​​of matrix $A$:

Since $$\left | A-\lambda I \right |=0 \implies \lambda_{1,2,3}=2$$

- We suppose that $A=PJP^{-1}$, where $J: diag(J_1(\lambda_1),J_1(\lambda_2),J_1(\lambda_3))$,

whence $e^{tA}=P\cdot e^{tJ}\cdot P^{-1}$.

- I compute $$e^{tJ}(2)=e^{tJ^1}\cdot \exp(2t)=\exp(2t)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
   & 1 &t&\dfrac{t^2}{2} \\ 
   & 0 &1&t \\ 
   & 0 &0&1 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
- But I have stuck when I **find matrix $P$**.

Anyone can help me!

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Thanks ** Mhenni Benghorbal**!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$P$ is made up of the columns from your eigenvectors. Here, you have two generalized eigenvectors.

We have (recall, these are not unique):

- $v_1 = (1,2,1)$
- $v_2 = (1,1,0)$
- $v_3 = (0,-1,0)$

You just find the inverse for the $P^{-1}$ for the other matrix.

**Update**

You should arrive at:

$$e^{tA} = \dfrac{e^{2 t}}{2}\begin{bmatrix} t^2+4 t+2 & -t^2-2 t & t^2 \\ 2 (t^2+3 t) & -2 (t^2+t-1) & 2 (t^2-t) \\ t^2+2 t & -t^2 & t^2-2 t+2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Wow! You're very good, **Amzoti**! I accected your ANS! Hihi :)   Since $Av=2v \implies v_1=(1,2,1)$. Since $Av=2v+v_1 \implies v_2,v_3$. I have remembered it!

Comment: I have found $$P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
 & 0 &0&1 \\ 
 & 1 &0&-1 \\ 
 & 1 & -1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$ Is it correct?

Comment: @kimtahe6: Very good, but be careful finding the generalized, sometimes it gets ugly where you have to use chaining. I may have given a bad hint on the other problem and am looking at if for V. Regards

Comment: @kimtahe6: Yes, that is correct for $P^{-1}$. I also added the final result, so you can compare. Regards

Comment: Yes, thanks **Amzoti**.

Comment: @ **Amzoti**: Of course, In this case :$Av=2v+v_1$, then we have $y=2x-1$ and $z=x-1$. We take $z=0 \implies x=y=1 \implies v_2(1,1,0)$. Next, $Av=2v+v_2$, then $x=z,=2x-1$. We take $x=0 \implies z=0,y=-1 \implies v_3(0,-1,0)$. (the same as your result) . But I don't understand **Why** we can write $Av=2v+v_1$, $Av=2v+v_2$? Can you help me! Thanks!

Comment: @kimtahe6: No time to explain now, but see these [*notes*](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~dummit/teaching_sp12/320_handout_6_supplement.pdf). Recall that we have algebraic and geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues. I think the paper explains the theory.

Comment: Nice post, and follow-up too! (And green is always nice!)

Comment: @ **Amzoti** : Now, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I can do it, because of your help. I always remember that, I'm thinking of you. Thank you very much,**Amzoti**.

Comment: Even more follow-up! You're a trooper, hangin' in there and always responding to comments, questions, etc.